# (React/Redux) Async issue in a Redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Wasn't able to successfully use solutions from past posts.

I'm trying to run an action every time the app loads using `useEffect` on app.js like this :

```
  26 | const App = () => {
  27 |   
  28 |   useEffect(() => {
> 29 |     store.dispatch(loadUser());
  30 |   }, []);
  31 | 
  32 |   return (
```

The error i'm getting :

```
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

The action :

```
export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
      dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING})

      const token = getState().auth.token

      const config = {
          headers : {
              "Content-type": "application/json"
          }
      }

      if (token) {
          config.headers["x-auth=token"] = token
      }

      axios.get("/api/auth/user", config) 
      .then(res => dispatch({
          type: USER_LOADED,
          payload: res.data
      }))
      .catch(err => {
          dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
          dispatch({
              type: AUTH_ERROR
          })
      })
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `loadUser ` returns a function, not an object. Seems like you havent configured redux-thunk properly

Comment: dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)) Is `returnErrors` an action?

Comment: Yes it comes from an errorActions file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux by itself is quite a simple workflow. Dispatched actions must be an object, usually with a type and a payload. This workflow is somewhat painful for async actions that require multiple dispatches through the phases of the action. That's where additional tools like [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or [Redux Sagas](https://redux-saga.js.org/) come in. It looks to me like you are using Redux Thunk but have not hooked the Thunk middleware up.

Wherever you are creating your store, you need to apply the redux thunk middleware like this.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Comment: Can you put the code up on CodeSandbox.io or something? Or add the code for `returnErrors`? Do you have a redux logger running to see which action its failing after so we can narrow down the specific instance?

Answer (score 2):

By default, actions in redux must return an object with a `type` key.

Your redux action creator is returning a function. This is a pattern most often used with the [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware. The `redux-thunk` middleware allows your actions to return a function that takes in the dispatch method to be called multiple times, if needed.

You'll want to install the `redux-thunk` package and include it in your middlewares array when you create your redux store.

Answer (score 0):

When you have async logic in actions then you have to integrate some kind of middleware with redux, i.e. `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga`. I prefer thunk as it's more simpler to use.